# conversion from byte to int and int to byte

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, byte, aes, steganography

v=b'F\xf4Y%\xfe\x1b\x8f\xaa\x1fY\xd0\xbf>\x03\x04t}C\xb2A}\x13#\xffw\x13\xcf\xfbb\x83\xdc\xc44\xd8\xb4\xad\x9e\x99\xfd\x9bv\xca\xcd\x1b"\xde\xcd\xd1\xact\xf0!E\x0b\xe0\x17\xac\xe7\x1e\x13 \x88\xa8$\xe8B\xf5h\x8f\xcaA\x9c\x83\xdciiL\xab\x98!\x0b$f\x02\x0b\xce\x1a\x14\xe9\x05"\x1d\xdd\xf86\x1fi\x13\x06\xa5\x1aX\xb3f!R\xab\x9d\xb6]r\xd8q\xb5+\x82\t\x06HU\xd4\xb2X\xe2\x0ca\x08\xcf\x92\xdc\xf3\xd4\x94Wf\xe7\x9f\xba3o\xacs\xc3\x94H\xed\xa1\xc9\x01q\xf5\xcbm\xdbn:\xda\x00\xbf\x87\xf1\xc3\xa4\x1a5*;\x8c\xde\xdd\x0b6\\xf3\x9aZ\xa4OH\x01\x96)V\xebv\xd4\x8b\xb3q\xef\xaa1\xa9\x0c\x9a>\x123\x10\xda\xfc\x0e\x1a\xcc\x0eQQ\xf7\x06\x86\xc4\x0e(h\xe3,~\xef|6\xceD{b\xa2\x8d\xcb\x85\xd7h\xb0\xf2^Hz\xf1C\xd6*SA\x80P\xb9F\xa2\xdf\x9e- z\xa5)\x1f\xea\xa2\x86\xf9\x90y\xc5^2\xdb\xe1\x12\x05|@\xb6P}\xf9H\xb4O\x9d\x8f\xdf\x8d\xde\x80\xea\xb7\x9e\xc2 @'

I've got this long result from AES encryption as intermediate result .I couldn't identify what format it is....thing is I want to convert this into integers ,so that I can convert it into binary to use for steganography
for example if get 1234 from from typecasting the above bytes into integer
ill convert it into 0001,0010,0011,0100 then hide these and again when i obtain these back from the image conversion to 1234 is easy ...but I want to construct this 1234 back to bytes string(back to aescipher)

Comment: If `v` is indeed the result of encryption, it's just a stream of bytes. You don't need to worry about what these bytes represent. Each byte, e.g., `v[0]`, `v[1]`, etc, are integers, so you can iterate over the bytestream and convert them to 1s and 0s as intended. I don't understand your last sentence and whether it describes another problem.

Comment: @Reti43 after using print(v[0],v[1]) I got them as 70,244 ....what I'm asking is how can I reconstruct (b'F\xf4Y%) this bytes part again from 70,244

Comment: `bytes([70, 244])` does exactly that.